# Log into a Linux machine and execute multiple commands

Tags: java, linux, perl, ssh, automation

I am trying to login and execute a set of commands through java from my remote computer (windows 7) into linux machine,

(Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10
Release:        5.10 )

Please look into the Perl script , which is working perfectly, same functionality needs to be achieved.

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 

use Net::SSH::Expect; 

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(   
    host     => "host123",  
    password => "passwd",  
    user     => "username",  
    raw_pty  => 1,  
    timeout  => 1, 
);
$ssh->login();

$ssh->exec("su - root");  
$ssh->exec("passwd");  
$ssh->exec("su - user");  
$ssh->exec("command1");  
$ssh->exec("subcommand"); 

my $output = $ssh->exec("subcommand 2");  
warn "$output\n";  
$ssh->exec("\n");

my $output2 = $ssh->exec("subcommand 3");  
warn "$output2\n";  
$ssh->exec("\n")
```

similar function need to be executed with the help of java..
currently i have written the following java code

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public void sshExecute() throws Exception {

    String username = "username";
    String password = "passwd";
    String hostname = "host123";
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    Object lastCommandOutput = null;
    logger.info("starting connection with " + hostname);

    Connection connection = new Connection(hostname);
    logger.info("connection object created..");

    connection.connect();
    connection.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

    Session session = connection.openSession();
    InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(session.getStdout());
    BufferedReader stdoutReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    logger.info("connected");

    String tempCommand = "su - root";
    String Pswd = "passwd";
    logger.info("sending command: " + tempCommand);

    session.execCommand(tempCommand + Pswd);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    session.execCommand("su - user");

    // Get output
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (true) {
        String line = stdoutReader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    String output = sb.toString();
    lastCommandOutput = output;
    logger.info("got output: " + output);

    stdoutReader.close();
}
```

This is working fine till line `session.execCommand("su - user");`. There,
it gives an error as :

```
java.io.IOException: A remote execution has already started.  java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: A remote execution has already started at com.user1.test.Assert.fail(Assert.java:35)
```

How to login twice, i.e su -root and then su - user, and also why can't we use `execCommand` more than once for a session? Is there any other way to achieve this instead of `execCommand`, to achieve the above functionality?

Comment: perhaps you should create the `su - user` string as well, just as you did with `su - root`

Comment: also, is this the same user you are logging on as, or a different user?

Comment: i tried it that way too , i.e creating string to it , but it is not working .

Comment: first logging on as root , and then as other user.

Comment: can you replace `su - user` with something like 'ls` and confirm if that works?

Comment: _first logging on as root_ Not being offensive at all, but allowing direct logon with root is extremely bad practice.

Comment: i tried changing it to "ls " , i am getting the same error .. please look into this, i just referred this " http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/FAQ.html#sessioncommands " , it seems like this exec command can be used only once .. if so , is there any other similar function to execute multiple command sequentially for one session?

Comment: well, you can try and chain the commands. `Session.execCommand("su - root && ls -l && df -h")`

Comment: Actually , that's perfect which you said , but after connecting to the server , to obtain the  functionality needed , i need to login as root first , and then as different "user" , and then need to execute the set of instructions under that respective user. please see the perl script , i need execution in that manner. , sub commands are the commands used under "user"

Comment: indeed, but perhaps look into giving a specific user sudo rights instead so it can run commands and disable direct login for root. :) Did you attempt the chaining?

Comment: no , i don't have much idea about it (chaining) , you mean method chaining? , could you please show how? in this case?

Comment: no, see my second last comment.

Comment: as example do `Session.execCommand("su - root && ls -l && df -h")`

Comment: Oh sorry , yes that i had thought of , but root needs to be authenticated with password, may be in execution, it can be tried like, in this format  "session.execCommand(tempCommand + Pswd + "su - user");" ? , but again i need to execute the further commands, with 1 second delay each and execCommand can be used only once

Comment: That won't work, you can try this however. `session.execCommand(tempCommand + Pswd && "su - user && whoami");`

Comment: Additionally you can setup ssh keys and get rid of the password as you are storing root's password in a script.

Comment: Sure, i will try that way:) thank you..

Comment: ok let me know.

Comment: Why you´re not using the Perl script? Java is not good to do this kind of task anyways.

Comment: actually , i want to merge complete operations in single workspace using java, for which i don't need to maintain separate perl script  , and there are packages in java specifically for these operations , that will make it more simpler then perl .. but am unaware of their proper usage :(

Comment: @GerhardBarnard could you please show me , how that can be done? , i tried but not getting proper out , i tried chaining as in your last second comment , only su - root is getting executed and warning is given on "Pswd " saying that the string is never used ..  i.e the commands except "su -root " (the first one)  are not being executed.

Comment: [here](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows) as well as [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html)

Comment: i tried another way , integrated perl with eclipse (EPIC) , installed cygwin (since new version of Expect module in above perl script needs cygwin to get installed on windows) , changed interpreter to cygwin on eclipse.. and ran perl script .. tadaa.. it worked !